# Entrada de números na mesma linha em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso ler três valores em uma única variável sendo o terceiro com vírgula.

Entrada: duas linhas de dados. Em cada linha haverá 3 valores, respectivamente dois inteiros e um valor com 2 casas decimais. EX:12 1 5.30
Valor de saída: EX: VALOR A PAGAR: R$ 15.50

Comment: Descreva melhor o problema

Comment: Você é iniciante?

Comment: Sim @nelson450, sou iniciante. Alterei para melhorar o compreendimento.

Comment: Por favor, dê exemplos de como será essa entrada e porquê precisa armazenar em apenas uma variável.

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291475/como-atribuir-3-valores-para-3-vari%c3%a1veis-em-apenas-uma-linha-de-entrada-em-pytho/461242#461242).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se todos fossem do mesmo valor bastava utilizar a função map que converteria para o tipo escolhido, mas como os tipos e diferente acredito que a única forma seria pegando eles em string e convertendo depois.

Aqui uma forma de fazer isso utilizando o split:

```
a,w,e = input().split(" ") # pega 3 valores na mesma linha e atribui a variáveis

# Converte o valor para os tipos necessários 
a = int(a)
w = int(w)
e = float(e)
```

No seu caso que precisa de 2 linhas basta fazer o mesmo procedimento novamente.

outra forma e utilizando uma lista para guardar todos os valores:

```
lista = []

lista = input().split(" ")
```

Assim todos os valores ficam na mesma "variável ", o procedimento de converter os valores também sera necessário, mas nesse caso recomendo que apenas o faça na hora do uso.